# Is it possible to execute drag and drop with robot using selenium

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, selenium, webdriver

I've been trying to use drag and drop and have used many different ways all failing for various reasons. The closest I've got to getting it to work is to use the robot(), I've been able to place my mouse on the item I wish to select and move my mouse to location I wish to drop my draggable element my only problem is that I cannot click and hold my draggable item.

The following is my code

```
       Robot r = new Robot(); 
        Thread.sleep(4000); 
        r.mouseMove(400,430 ); 
        r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        Thread.sleep(2000); 
        r.mouseMove(600, 430); 
        r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

Comment: can you just raise the dnd events with mock event objects? the actual human interaction parts are not that testable, nor need they be really; it's pretty reliable; it's the underling actions that those events trigger that needs to be tested, and good concern separation helps there.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this could you expand your explanation a little? What do you mean by"can you just raise the dnd events with mock event objects"